# How can i clone a dragged element in jqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can i clone a dragged element and make the original element stay in its original place. I want the word "element" in div below to be cloned and then i want the clone to have the ability to append in the box with the black border if it is dropped over it. Here is my code:-

```js
$(window).load(function(){


$('.me').draggable({
                helper:"clone",
                containment:"document"
});

$('#a').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        drop:function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
        }
});

});
```

```css
  #a{
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>





  
<span class="me">element</span>




  <div id="a"></div>
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Use "clone()" instead of "detach()"? Or am I getting your question wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the element on `dragstop` event

**EDIT**

As suggested by Kevkong in his comment use `clone` instead of `detach` in `drop` event and simply achieve this

```js
$(window).load(function(){


    $('.me').draggable({
                    helper:"clone",
                    containment:"document"
    });

    $('#a').droppable({
            greedy: true,
            drop:function(event, ui) {
                ui.draggable.clone().appendTo($(this));
                ui.helper.data('dropped', true);
            }
    });
 
    });
```

```css
#a{
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 
  
<span class="me">element</span>
 
<div id="a"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. It works but there is one problem, the element keeps cloning while it is in the box. How can i solve this. sorry i'm confused at jqueryui.

Comment: @Axmednuur Updated my answer.Please check

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to your question you could still just use close() instead of detach() in the drop function, no need for the extra code.

Comment: @Kevkong Thanks for your info.Updated the answer.Removed lots of code.Superb.Never knew this.Thanks